# Test if a list of environment variables are all set to some values

Tags: bash

In Bash, how should I write the boolean condition that says:

Given a list of environment variables $A, $B, and $C, execute `echo Succeeds!` only if all of them are set to some values. Otherwise, execute `exit -1`.

Or, in pseudocode:

```
if (all_env_vars_set_to_some_value($A, $B, $C)) {
    echo 'Succeeds!';
else {
    exit -1;
}
```

Comment: Do you care if the variables are environment variables (i.e., have their export flag set) or just that they are set to some (possibly empty) value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this in BASH:

```
if [[ -n "$A" && -n "$B" && -n "$C" ]]; then
    echo 'Succeeds!'
else
    exit -1
fi
```

As per `man test:

```
-n STRING
       the length of STRING is nonzero
```

Comment: Same comments as the other answer: This will test if variables are set, not that they are existing environmental variables. You have two flaws here: 1. if the script is _sourced_ with the variables set, it'll pass the test. 2. if the variables are set to an empty value, it'll not pass the test. (Maybe point 2 is irrelevant).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I'm not sure if the user actually cares that the export flag is set on each variable, as long as the variable is set in the current shell (whether because it was manually set or inherited from the parent via the environment). Since setting the export flag is an idempotent operation, the script can alway just execute `export A B C` prior to starting any children.

Comment: @chepner then the question is unclear as it clearly states _environment variables_.

Comment: There are enough issues with the question that I'm not sure the OP is aware of the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Use [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
if [ 'X' = "${A:+${B:+${C:+X}}}" ]; then
    echo 'Success!'
else
    exit -1
fi
```

If empty values are allowable and only *unset* variables are to be disallowed then simply remove the : from each variable expansion in the above snippet.

But also note that `exit -1` doesn't get you a `-1` return code from the script. It gets you `255`.

Comment: This will test if variables are set, not that they are existing environmental variables. You have two flaws here: 1. if the script is _sourced_ with the variables set, it'll pass the test. 2. if the variables are set to an empty value, it'll not pass the test. (Maybe point 2 is irrelevant).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I think the discussion on the other answer is accurate. You have a point assuming the OP meant exported variables. I think that is unlikely. The empty value bit is easily fixed (and in fact I accidentally wrote that version the first time and had an alternate version that could *only* handle the unset-only checking that I decided not to include because I thought that was again unlikely to be the desired goal).

Comment: Good point. Eventually, when we understand the OP's question, we'll fix it.